# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line in XML Layout

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view

here is my code. when i inflate the view showing exception called android.view.InflateException : Binary XML line #8 in my MainActivity class. also crash the application,
if any wrongs in code?.Please help me

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <com.example.newscratch.PaintView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PaintView.java**

```
package com.example.newscratch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "PaintView";
Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
Bitmap Transparent;
Bitmap overlay;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
private boolean isTouched = false;

// List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public PaintView(Activity context) {
    super(context);
    initView(context);
}

 private void initView(Activity context) {
     setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.main);
        Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        c2 = new Canvas();
        c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
          //        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);

        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
}

private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) {
  final Point point = new Point();
   point.x = display.getWidth();
   point.y = display.getHeight();
  return point;
 }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("onDraw");
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 50, paint);
    if(isTouched)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    isTouched = true;
    X = (int) event.getX();
    Y = (int) event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
 }

  class Point {
float x, y;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return x + ", " + y;
}
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//        View bgView = findViewById(R.id.background);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Comment: Have you added proper library for what you are trying to develop if yes then Try to clean your project or else restart the eclipse. or if no then check twice properly and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define two more constrcutors in your `PaintView` class...

```
    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the stacktrace, it's not easy...

At first sight : an appropriate constructor is missing in your PaintView class.

Add a constructor with this signature :

```
public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
     super(...);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to implement the "XML constructor". You should add:

```
public PaintView((Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context);
}
```

see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29) for more information.